# get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk_news'

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

views.py:

```
class NewsCommentsUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ('comment',)
    template_name = 'news/comment_edit.html'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('news_detail', args=[str(self.object.news.id)])

    def get(self, request):
        return Comment.objects.get(pk_news=self.request.GET.get('news_id'), pk=self.request.GET.get('id'))

    def test_func(self):
        obj = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user.has_perm('news.all') or self.request.user.has_perm('news.delete_news') or obj.author == self.request.user:
            return True
```

urls.py:

```
path('<int:pk_news>/comment_edit/<int:pk>/', NewsCommentsUpdateView.as_view(), name='comment_edit'),
path('<int:pk_news>/comment-delete/<int:pk>/', NewsCommentsDeleteView.as_view(), name='comment_delete'),
```

template:

```
{% for comment in object.comments.all %}
                        <a href="{% url 'comment_edit'  pk_news=news.pk pk=comment.pk %}">Edit</a> |
                        <a href="{% url 'comment_delete'  pk_news=news.pk pk=comment.pk %}">Delete</a>
{% endfor %}
```

It does not work and gives me an error (get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk_news').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url parameters are passed to the `get` (`post`, `put`, etc.) functions. Since these do *not* belong to the [*query string* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), these are thus not in the `request.GET`.

You thus process these with:

```
class NewsCommentsUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ('comment',)
    template_name = 'news/comment_edit.html'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('news_detail', args=[str(self.object.news.id)])

    def get(self, request, pk_news, pk):
        return Comment.objects.get(pk_news=pk_news, pk=pk)

    def test_func(self):
        obj = self.get_object()
        return self.request.user.has_perm('news.all') or \
               self.request.user.has_perm('news.delete_news') or \
               obj.author == self.request.user
```

Your `get`, `post`, etc. requests should return a [**`HttpResponse`** object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse) not a model object. You thus should process this item accordingly. Likely you want this to be the `.get_object()` method. In that case you access the URL parameters with `self.kwargs`:

```
class NewsCommentsUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ('comment',)
    template_name = 'news/comment_edit.html'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('news_detail', args=[str(self.object.news.id)])

    def get_object(self, *__, **___):
        return Comment.objects.get(pk_news=self.kwargs['pk_news'], pk=self.kwargs['pk'])

    def test_func(self):
        obj = self.get_object()
        return self.request.user.has_perm('news.all') or \
               self.request.user.has_perm('news.delete_news') or \
               obj.author == self.request.user
```

Comment: Also that `get` method is returning a model instance instead of a response. (perhaps it should be `get_object` instead?)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: great point! I did not read the what the `get` method was doing. Updated accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, your tips worked perfectly, I just needed to delete part ‍‍‍‍ pk_news and it's work.